# Polymer 1.0 main html document structure

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, polymer, web-frontend

I'm experimenting with Polymer. I love how the web components work. Now I want to build a web app. My question is: Should I have a main element (called app-element for example) that hosts all other elements and works as an orchestrator? One big element in the main html document that contains the JS code to handle all other elements? If yes do these elements exist in iron-elements or something? If not then how do I manage the JS code that handles the elements? pure js?

For people that used Angular 1, I remember the "app" controller? that was set to the body tag? This was a global controller to control all directives inside that html document. My question is do I follow a similar pattern with Polymer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taylor Savage (Polymer Product Manager) addresses this in the [Polymer Summit 2015 opening keynote](https://youtu.be/jVn8tlnwAEs?list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J&t=1169) (the video is timed to kick off exactly where Taylor discusses the topic).

Up to now the Polymer team has viewed Polymer as "legos". You can put them together however you want. E.g. if you want routing, you can wrap your favorite routing library in an element. Polymer is a "swiss army knife" of tools that you use as you need. It's not a framework. It doesn't enforce app-level architecture. It's up to you decide. Which makes it hard on developers to know where to start.

So, here's three options off the top of my head:

- Design your own architecture however you see fit
- Wait for the "Carbon" elements that are designed to address application architecture (mentioned in the keynote)
- Check out the Polymer Starter Kit. You'll see a lot of "container" or "parent" elements (e.g. elements that contain and unite children or "leaf node" elements). The main document is essentially just a declaration of all of these top-level container elements.